# Do data conversion after Django model object is fetched

Tags: django, django-models, model

I want to save the python dictionary inside the Django model as JSON and I want to convert that JSON back into a python dictionary when that data is fetched.

I know I can do it inside view but I want to implement it in the model so it can return dictionary object when queried.

is there any signal or any post_fetch method that I can use to achieve it, I couldn't find anything googling it...

Comment: In Django versions >=3.1 you can simply use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield). In versions lower than that if you use PostgreSQL you can use it's JSONField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into simply using the Python JSON package, unless you are using Postgres as your database - in which case [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) is the way to go. The json package is [explained here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) and you could use it in a model like so if I understand what you are saying:

```
import json

class MyModel(models.Model):
    json_field = models.TextField() # or you can use JSONField if using Postgres

    @property
    def get_json_field_as_dictionary(self):
       return json.loads(self.json_field)

   def set_json_field(self, mydict):
       self.json_field = json.dumps(mydict)

    @classmethod
    def get_json_from_dictionary(cls, mydict):
        return json.dumps(mydict)
```

When you are saving to the database, you can use `json.dumps(myDictionary)` or convert the dictionary to JSON by calling `MyModelObject.set_json_field(myDictionary)` to convert a Python dictionary to JSON and then store it in the `json_field` of the model. To retrieve the JSON data as a dictionary, you simply call `MyModel.objects.last().get_json_field_as_dictionary` (or whatever you prefer to call it, `json_dictionary` perhaps so it would be `MyModel.objects.last().json_dictionary`) and it will return the value of that property as if it were an element in the model without having to do the conversion each time.

Or, if you are using Postgres as your backend, this is a lot easier with [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    json_field = models.JSONField(null=True)
```

And to save:

```
    myObject = myModel.objects.create(json_field=myDictionary)
```

If you clarify I can update my answer to explain better.

Comment: yeah I am using that but I want to do the conversion without running any additional function i.e if I do MyModel.objects.last().json_field it should give me python dict. More like how can I do get JSONField like behavior if it is I am using an older version of Django

Comment: Just call MyModel.objects.last().get_json_field_as_dictionary (or whatever you want to call it) and it will do that - a property acts just like an element of the model but is a function/method which returns a value.

Comment: That is clever, I never thought about it, thank a lot this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField). It allows storing data encoded as JSON and retrieve them as the corresponding Python data type, including dictionary.

JSONField only works on PostgreSQL with `Django < 3.1`, but works on any database with `Django >= 3.1`.